# How to describe a piece-wise function in words?

Tags: definition

Suppose we want to describe a peice-wise function in words. My last post was down-voted because it was not clear.

Here is what I'm trying to desribe.

Function $F:D\to\mathbb{R}$, $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_n=D$ and

$$F(x)=\begin{cases}
F_1(x) & x=A_1\\
F_2(x) & x=A_2\\
F_3(x) & x=A_3 \\
... & ... \\
... & ... \\
\text{Undefined} & \text{Everywhere Else}
\end{cases}
$$

Here is my description

Consider piece-wise function $F:D\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $D\subseteq {\mathbb{R}}$ is partitioned into *chosen subsets* $A_1,A_2,...A_n$ with $F_1(x)$ defined on $x\in A_1$, $F_2(x)$ is defined on $x\in A_2$ and so on.

Is this clear enough?

[Here is the original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3290465/edit)

Comment: Typos: $x=A_1,x=A_2,x=A_3$ should be $x\in A_1,x\in A_2,x\in A_3$.

Comment: Also, once you declare a domain $D$, there's no need for the "undefined" case.

Comment: In any case, what is your question?

Comment: Is my desription, in words, clear. I was downvoted on my last post.

Comment: Also, in your "word" version, it's not just that $F_k(x)$ is defined on $A_k$. You want to say that $F(x)$ is _equal_ to $F_k(x)$ on $A_k$.

Comment: Could you put your own "word" version in your answer. I'm really bad at this. Plus I was downvoted,

Comment: Also, you are only allowing finitely many pieces, but a piecewise functions can be based on an arbitrary partition of the domain.

Comment: Your description is clear enough as to what you _mean_.

Comment: Where did you declare that $A_1,...,A_n$ are pairwise disjpint?

Comment: In the word version, I would use "partitioned into" rather than "split into", but that's just a preference. It's clear either way.

Comment: I didn't. Is that why I was downvoted,

Comment: Well, there you have it. You need the parts to be pairwise disjoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you want to emphasize that $F$ is piecewise, and just give a name to the piecewise regions, you can say:

   > Let $F:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined piecewise on a given partition $D_1,\ldots, D_n$ of $D$.
2. If you want to emphasize your interest in a particular partition ("chosen subsets") where $F$ is defined piecewise, you can say:

   > Suppose the domain $D$ is partitioned into particular nonoverlapping subsets $D_1,\ldots, D_n$, and that $F$ is a real-valued function that can be defined piecewise within each region.
3. If you want to emphasize or define what it means *to be piecewise*, you can say:

   > Consider a real-valued function $F$ defined piecewise on a domain $D$ as follows: $D$ is partitioned into nonoverlapping subsets $D_1, \ldots, D_n$, and there is a function $F_i:D_i \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined on each region. The overall function $F$ is defined by $F(x) = F_i(x)$ whenever $x\in D_i$, which uniquely specifies $F$ throughout all of $D$.